# Is there a UK equivalent to the USA's FERPA?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, education, data-protection

The Family Education Rights and Privacy Act (FERPA) describes rights students have to their private records in the United States. Is there an equivalent for students in the United Kingdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UK does not have an education-specific *data-protection* law.

There are several laws touching on access to and privacy of educational records, though, including the [Children Act 1989](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1989/41/part/XI), the [Education Act 1996](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/56/part/IX/chapter/IV) and the [Education Act 2005](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2005/18/part/4/crossheading/information).

And schools are also generally covered under the [Data Protection Act 1988](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/1998/29) (DPA) and the [General Data Protection Regulation](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/). Under DPA, the government has also issued [regulations governing access to student records](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2005/1437/contents/made), and these also govern access to records. For some basic information on the regs, you can check out [this article from the ICO](https://ico.org.uk/for-the-public/schools/pupils-info/).